# Dcast multiple observation in a 1 cell in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dcast

I have one R dataframe

```
Customer    Month   BaseVolume  IncrementalVolume   TradeSpend
10          Jan         11            1             110
10          Feb         12            2             120
20          Jan         21            7             210
20          Feb         22            8             220
```

Which I want to convert it like this,

```
Customer    Jan                    Feb  
10          BaseVolume 11         BaseVolume 12
            IncrementalVolume 1   IncrementalVolume 2 
            TradeSpend 110        TradeSpend 120

20         BaseVolume 21          BaseVolume 22
           IncrementalVolume 7    IncrementalVolume 8 
           TradeSpend 210         TradeSpend 220
```

I tried dcast (reshape) but I couldn't get this result.  Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is already [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43629759/3817004), I feel it can improved in some respect to come closer to the expected output:

- the OP has specified the month to appear in the order `Jan`, `Feb`
- the output is difficult to read
- munging of columns should take place *before* the `dcast()`

We'll start with reshaping the input data from wide to long format but make sure that `Month` will appear in the correct order:

```
molten <- melt(dt1, id.vars = c("Customer", "Month"))
# turn Month into factor with levels in the given order
molten[, Month := forcats::fct_inorder(Month)]
```

Now, a new `text` column is created in long format *before* the call to `dcast()`:

```
molten[, text := paste(variable, value)]
dcast(molten, Customer + variable ~ Month, value.var = "text")[, variable := NULL][]
#   Customer                 Jan                 Feb
#1:       10       BaseVolume 11       BaseVolume 12
#2:       10 IncrementalVolume 1 IncrementalVolume 2
#3:       10      TradeSpend 110      TradeSpend 120
#4:       20       BaseVolume 21       BaseVolume 22
#5:       20 IncrementalVolume 7 IncrementalVolume 8
#6:       20      TradeSpend 210      TradeSpend 220
```

The result is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43629759/3817004) but has the months in the expected order.

---

**N.B.** Unfortunately, the approach to collapse also the rows per `Customer` doesn't work as line breaks aren't respected when printed:

```
dcast(molten, Customer ~ Month, value.var = "text", paste0, collapse = "\n")
#   Customer                                                Jan                                                Feb
#1:       10 BaseVolume 11\nIncrementalVolume 1\nTradeSpend 110 BaseVolume 12\nIncrementalVolume 2\nTradeSpend 120
#2:       20 BaseVolume 21\nIncrementalVolume 7\nTradeSpend 210 BaseVolume 22\nIncrementalVolume 8\nTradeSpend 220
```

---

The `text` column can be left aligned by padding white space to the right (the minimum lengths is determined by the character length of the longest string):

```
molten[, text := paste(variable, value)]
molten[, text := stringr::str_pad(text, max(nchar(text)), "right")]
dcast(molten, Customer + variable ~ Month, value.var = "text")[, variable := NULL][]
#   Customer                 Jan                 Feb
#1:       10 BaseVolume 11       BaseVolume 12      
#2:       10 IncrementalVolume 1 IncrementalVolume 2
#3:       10 TradeSpend 110      TradeSpend 120     
#4:       20 BaseVolume 21       BaseVolume 22      
#5:       20 IncrementalVolume 7 IncrementalVolume 8
#6:       20 TradeSpend 210      TradeSpend 220
```

Or, the `text` column can be aligned in itself:

```
fmt <- stringr::str_interp("%-${n}s %3i", list(n = molten[, max(nchar(levels(variable)))]))
molten[, text := sprintf(fmt, variable, value)]
dcast(molten, Customer + variable ~ Month, value.var = "text")[, variable := NULL][]
#   Customer                   Jan                   Feb
#1:       10 BaseVolume         11 BaseVolume         12
#2:       10 IncrementalVolume   1 IncrementalVolume   2
#3:       10 TradeSpend        110 TradeSpend        120
#4:       20 BaseVolume         21 BaseVolume         22
#5:       20 IncrementalVolume   7 IncrementalVolume   8
#6:       20 TradeSpend        210 TradeSpend        220
```

Here, the format to be used in `sprintf()` is also created dynamically by using string interpolation:

```
fmt
#[1] "%-17s %3i"
```

Note that the character length of the longest *level* of `variable` is used here as `melt()` has turned `variable` to factor by default.

---

The answer could have been much simpler as the latest versions of `data.table` allow to reshape multiple columns simultaneously:

```
molten <- melt(dt1, id.vars = c("Customer", "Month"))
molten[, Month := forcats::fct_inorder(Month)]
dcast(molten, Customer + variable ~ Month, value.var = c("variable", "value"))
#   Customer          variable    variable.1_Jan    variable.1_Feb value_Jan value_Feb
#1:       10        BaseVolume        BaseVolume        BaseVolume        11        12
#2:       10 IncrementalVolume IncrementalVolume IncrementalVolume         1         2
#3:       10        TradeSpend        TradeSpend        TradeSpend       110       120
#4:       20        BaseVolume        BaseVolume        BaseVolume        21        22
#5:       20 IncrementalVolume IncrementalVolume IncrementalVolume         7         8
#6:       20        TradeSpend        TradeSpend        TradeSpend       210       220
```

but unfortunately it is lacking an option to easily reorder the columns in alternating order, i.e., all columns belonging to `Jan`, then `Feb` etc.

Comment: @Frank I've added a comment in https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/716 seconding your suggestion and pointing to this example.

Answer (score 1):

What you could try is the following (In your case say your data is df1 you need to do `setDT(df1)` before any of the actions that I mention):

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- structure(list(Customer = c(10L, 10L, 20L, 20L), Month = c("Jan", 
"Feb", "Jan", "Feb"), BaseVolume = c(11L, 12L, 21L, 22L), IncrementalVolume = c(1L, 
2L, 7L, 8L), TradeSpend = c(110L, 120L, 210L, 220L)), .Names = c("Customer", 
"Month", "BaseVolume", "IncrementalVolume", "TradeSpend"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

res <- dcast(melt(dt1, id.vars = c("Customer", "Month")), Customer + variable~ Month)

> res
   Customer          variable Feb Jan
1:       10        BaseVolume  12  11
2:       10 IncrementalVolume   2   1
3:       10        TradeSpend 120 110
4:       20        BaseVolume  22  21
5:       20 IncrementalVolume   8   7
6:       20        TradeSpend 220 210
```

In case you want them together you can do the following:

```
update_cols <- which(!names(res) %in% c("Customer", "variable"))
res[, (update_cols):= lapply(.SD, function(x) paste(variable, x)), .SDcols = update_cols][, variable:= NULL]
```

Which gives:

```
> res
     Customer            Feb                 Jan
1:       10       BaseVolume 12       BaseVolume 11
2:       10 IncrementalVolume 2 IncrementalVolume 1
3:       10      TradeSpend 120      TradeSpend 110
4:       20       BaseVolume 22       BaseVolume 21
5:       20 IncrementalVolume 8 IncrementalVolume 7
6:       20      TradeSpend 220      TradeSpend 210
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks @User2321